# On a technical level, why can computers not distinguish unplugged second monitors from turned-off ones?

Tags: multiple-monitors

Every OS that I've ever used has the following behavior:

- Compared to its one-screen behavior, the machine behaves differently when a secondary monitor is plugged in
- ...even if that monitor is turned off

This suggests that my machines are incapable of telling the difference between a plugged-in-but-turned-off monitor and a turned-on monitor. I doubt that such a limitation is due to incompetence or oversight. So, why is such a limitation in place? What, technically, is preventing every machine I've ever owned from telling the difference between a powered-on and powered-off secondary monitor? One would assume that "powered-off" should be treated just like "unplugged", but that is never the case.

Comment: The Question you've asked is quite confusing. To What I've understood, I think you end up asking the opposite question than what your title states... I would really suggest you to rewrite your question

Comment: Because even though the display panel itself is "off" the rest of the monitor is not. There are some electronics running that connect to the computer telling it that a monitor is connected. If you don't want the monitor to be seen then disconnect it's power input. If it is detected then the monitor is in "standby", it is **not** turned "off".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is not specified. Display Data Channel (DDC) does not offers information about the power state of a display. Because, in the first place, it is up to display manufacturers to decided whether a display is detectable when off or even unpowered.

Most VGA and DVI displays I used in the past could be detected even when unpowered. They used power supplied by the PC for their DDC chips.

With HDMI and especially DisplayPort displays, I had very mixed results. Some could not be detected when off, even if it they still had power.

To make it even more confusing: HDMI and DisplayPort *also* offer (minimal) power supply capabilities for DDC chips. It’s up to the manufacturer.

The operating system is not part of the equation.

Comment: I would say that a monitor that is detected is in a low power "standby" waiting to show an image rather than "off". The same way that laptops suspend to RAM are ready to go at a moments notice so are displays that are in standby. If it were truly "off" then the display would not be detectable at all.

Comment: @Mokubai That’s the thing: With DDC power from the computer, some displays are detectable even when not connected to mains at all.